# Handle empty structs in Objective-C (Coordinate in custom class)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, struct

I have a custom class that has as an instance variable of a coordinate:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D eventLocation;
@property(nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D eventLocation;
```

I'm parsing an xml file that has an optional field that may or may not be there.
If it is i set it like so:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
NSArray *coordinateArray = [paramValue componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
if ([coordinateArray count] >= 2) {
    location.latitude = [[coordinateArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [[coordinateArray objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Coordinate problem");
}
info.eventLocation = location;
```

What I do this is basically add an annotation on a map

```
annotation.coordinate = alert.info.eventLocation;
```

I know I need to do some checking here to make sure that that exists but I'm not allowed to do a `if (info.eventLocation == nil)` or even  `if (info.eventLocation.latitude == nil)`

This seems like a very basic question but I've done some searching and no one's been able to really provide a good answer/idea. Is my architecture completely off?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a struct, there's not such thing as a `nil` value. Objective-C will initialize structs to 0 if they are object instance variables, so if you don't set a value for `eventLocation`, `annotation.coordinate.longitude` and `eventLocation.lattitude` will both be 0. Since this is a valid location, it's not a useful marker.

I would define a non-phyical value:

```
static const CLLocationDegrees emptyLocation = -1000.0;
static const CLLocationCoordinate2D emptyLocationCoordinate = {emptyLocation, emptyLocation}
```

and then assign this value to your `alert.info.eventLocation = EmptyLocationCoordinate` to represent an empty value. You can then check if `(alert.info.eventLocation == emptyLocationCoordinate)`.

Comment: When i add this to my .h file of my custom object I'm getting errors: 
Initializer element is not constant
(near initialization for 'EmptyLocationCoordinate.latitude') 
Initializer element is not constant
(near initialization for 'EmptyLocationCoordinate.longitude')

Comment: Actually, the 
alert.info.eventLocation = EmptyLocationCoordinate
still gives a "Invalid operands to binary !=" Error

Comment: Ah, perhaps you need to #define EmptyLocation.

Comment: It's not quite accurate to say Objective-C will initialize structs to 0. It will zero out instance variables, but structs created on the stack are treated just like any other auto variable.

Comment: @aleclerc: That assignment doesn't involve any != operator, so I think your error is elsewhere.

Comment: @chuck sorry I was using the comparison with both != and == in different places

Comment: You may also use `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()` to test if a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is valid. It would be invalid if its latitude is greater than 90 degrees or less than -90 degrees or its longitude is greater than 180 degrees or less than -180 degrees.

Answer (score 4):

I used the code above except it wouldn't let me declare a const with another const, so i simply changed it to:

```
static const CLLocationDegrees EmptyLocation = -1000.0;
static const CLLocationCoordinate2D EmptyLocationCoordinate = {-1000.0, -1000.0};
```

I also added in my init for the class:

```
eventLocation = EmptyLocationCoordinate;
```

Thanks for the help Barry.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness sake, you can use the `kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid` constant to hold a reference to an invalid `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. (see: [@Klaas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110167/12604))